# Error while running Hadoop java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: hadoop

I did this tutorial  [Running Hadoop On Ubuntu Linux (Single-Node Cluster)](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) and everything worked fine. After that I tried this [Running Hadoop On Ubuntu Linux (Multi-Node Cluster)enter link description here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) but I got following eror:

Logs file:

```
    2012-11-15 18:40:39,258 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:50060/mapOutput?job=job_201211151832_0002&map=attempt_201211151832_0002_m_000000_0&reduce=0
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1613)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.getInputStream(ReduceTask.java:1639)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.setupSecureConnection(ReduceTask.java:1575)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.getMapOutput(ReduceTask.java:1483)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.copyOutput(ReduceTask.java:1394)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.run(ReduceTask.java:1326)
```

Error in terminal:

```
12/11/15 18:42:18 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://localhost:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201211151832_0002_m_000001_0&filter=stderr
```

I checked also if it is an issue with running out of space on disk with log directory, but it's not.

I'm using Hadoop 1.0.4.

What causes this error ?

Some additional information:
Master node is LinuxMint 13 x64 (Oracle Java 7 x64) and slave node is Ubuntu 12.04 x86 (Oracle Java x86).

Is it possible that using two different versions of Java (x86 and x64) causes this error ?

Comment: Not exactly sure why it's happening. But, the o/p of the mapper is written to the local node and not HDFS. And the reducer uses HTTP to fetch the output of the mappers. This is where the exception is being thrown. One thing is to make sure that all the nodes can talk to each other.

Comment: Ok, I've solved this issue. The problem was that I followed strictly the tutorial and I named my computers as master,slave and slave1 in masters and slaves files whereas I should have used their real names

Comment: @michalskuza Can you explain it in detail here and accept your own answer? I am facing a similar issue and I'm not really sure how to fix it.

Comment: You have to use unix boxes names which are located in /etc/hosts.
Hope it'll help to solve the problem.